# Sum of digits of a number using While

Tags: python, while-loop, sum

How can I do the sum of numbers that was given on a function?
Like this: `def sum (123)`
How can I make python sum 123 to give 6 using while?

```
def calc_soma(num):
    ns = str(num)
    soma = 0
    while soma < len(ns):
        soma = eval(ns[soma])
        soma = soma + 1
    return soma
```

I tried this but it doesn't work. I'm new on python so i don't no many things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `soma` to hold indices AND the result. Here is a modified version:

```
>>> def calc_soma(num):
...     ns = str(num)
...     soma = 0
...     indic = 0
...     while indic < len(ns):
...         soma += int(ns[indic])
...         indic = indic + 1
...     return soma
...
>>> calc_soma(123)
6
>>> calc_soma(1048)
13
```

If you want to iterate over the `str`, you can use list comprehension:

```
>>> sum([int(i) for i in str(123)])
6
>>> sum([int(i) for i in str(2048)])
14
```

You can also get rid of the `[/]`:

```
sum(int(i) for i in str(123))
```

(Also, check barak manos's answer. You can "mathematically" do that)

Comment: Sorry for the question but why do you += in "soma += int(ns[indic])" instead of just = ?

Answer (score 6):

Why do you convert it to a string when you can simply get each digit from the integer?

```
while num > 0:
    soma += num%10
    num /= 10
```

Comment: Damn. Didn't see your answer or else I wouldn't have posted mine :( +1 Dude

Answer (score 0):

Basically you `mod` it:

```
>>> total = 0
>>> num = 123
>>> while num > 0:
...     total += num % 10
...     num /= 10
...
...
>>> total
6
```

You could use `str`, but that would be slow.